# How many equivalence classes does $\sim$ gives rise to?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

**Let $\sim$ be a relation on $\mathbb R$ defined by $$ x \sim y \Longleftrightarrow(x \cdot y>0) \vee(x=y=0)$$
How many equivalence classes does $\sim$ gives rise to?**

**My answer:** $\infty$. The definition in my textbook of a equivalence class is 
$$[a]=\{ x \in A \mid x \sim a  \}$$

In this case $A=\mathbb R$ and $a=y$.

The definition of $\sim$ in the problem says that $x$ and $y$ are related iff $sgn(x)=sgn(y)$ or $x=y=0$. There is an infinite number which have the same sign as [a]. So my conclusion is that there are infinite equivalence classes.

I know I'm wrong. What are my mistakes and how can I correct them?

I'm not sure which tools (theorems, definitions etc.) I should use.

Comment: Forgot to write the problem formulation down. I has now been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three.

1) Positive numbers are equivalent to each other, since $xy>0$ if $x,y>0$;

2) Negative numbers are equivalent to each other, since $xy>0$ if $x,y<0$;

3) $0$ is equivalent only to itself, since $0x=0$.

Moreover a positive number and a negative number are not equivalent, since $xy<0$.

You are confusing the number of classes with the cardinality (i.e. number of elements) of a class.

Comment: How would you then describe  $\mathbb R /  \sim$ ?

Comment: $\{-1,0,1\}$: you just take a representative for each class.

Comment: What I mean is $\mathbb R / \sim = 3$?

Comment: No. That is the cardinality of the set, not the set. But actually your original question was the cardinality of the quotient set, and that is 3.

Comment: So $\mid \mathbb R \diagup \sim \mid = 3$

Comment: I'm still not sure what $\mathbb R \diagup \sim$ describes?